# I am trying to save model class data in DB using Spring with Kotlin but I am getting exception

Tags: mysql, sql, spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I am learning Spring with Kotlin and I am getting below exceptions while saving data in the local Database

My Rest Controller looks like below

```
@RestController
class MarketPlaceController(val service: MessageService) {

@GetMapping("/homepage")
fun getHomePage() = "NFTs Marketplace"

@GetMapping("/errorpage")
fun getErrorPage() = "This is error"

private var NFTs = mutableListOf(
    Message(1, "Title #1", "Description #1"),
    Message(2, "Sneaky Vampire Syndicate", "Description #2"),
    Message(3, "The Sevens (Official)", "Description #3"),
    Message(4, "Art Blocks Curated", "Description #4"),
    Message(5, "Pudgy Penguins", "Description #5"),
)

@GetMapping("")
fun getNFTs() = service.findMessages()

@PostMapping("")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
fun postNFT(@RequestBody nft: Message): Message {
    val maxId = NFTs.map { it.id }.maxOrNull() ?: 0
    val nextId = maxId + 1
    val newNft = Message(id = nextId, title = nft.title, message = nft.message)
    service.post(newNft)
    return newNft
}

@GetMapping("/{id}")
fun getNFTById(@PathVariable id: Int): Message? {
    val nft = NFTs.firstOrNull { it.id == id }
    return nft ?: throw NFTNotFoundException()
}

}

@Service
class MessageService(val db: MessageRepository) {

fun findMessages(): List<Message> = db.findMessages()

fun post(message: Message) {
    db.save(message)
}
 }

interface MessageRepository : CrudRepository<Message, String> {

@Query("select * from messages")
fun findMessages(): List<Message>
 }
```

Created sql scheme inside resources ->sql -> schema.sql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS messages
(
id   VARCHAR(60) DEFAULT RANDOM_UUID() PRIMARY KEY,
title VARCHAR NOT NULL,
message VARCHAR NOT NULL
);
```

Now after running code and using POST service then I am getting 500 Internal Server Error

[image]

but while using the GET data I am getting a successful empty error as nothing is save as of now.

My **application.properties** inside src-> main -> resources

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./data/testdb
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.sql.init.schema-locations=classpath:sql/schema.sql
spring.sql.init.mode=always
```

Any help is appreciable.

Thanks in advance

Edit #1

Exception

```
Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported]
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.relational.core.conversion.DbActionExecutionException: Failed to execute InsertRoot{entity=Message(id=6, title=Rakshit, message=hi I am here and what about you?), idValueSource=NONE}] with root cause
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "messages" not found (candidates are: "MESSAGES"); SQL statement:
INSERT INTO "messages" ("id", "message", "title") VALUES (?, ?, ?) [42103-214]
```

Comment: Could you add an exception log to get a better answer?

Comment: @Pemassi apologies, added my exception log in my question

Comment: Could you try to change schema location to `classpath:/META-INF/resources/sql/schema.sql` or `classpath:/resources/sql/schema.sql`?

Comment: I tried updating the scheme location but I got error which says  `No schema scripts found at location 'classpath:/resources/sql/schema.sql'`.

Comment: With my original schema location I am able to fetch an empty list before hand but unable to add data in DB @Pemassi

Comment: Does it have something to do with **Bean**? As I didn't add any in my code yet

Comment: The exception says cannot find the table, so when init the DB with the script, looks like not worked well. Could you add `BEGIN TRANSACTION;` at the first and `COMMIT;` at the end of the script? It can happen if auto-commit is not enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a specification of the data here.

```kotlin
@Table("MESSAGES")
data class Message(@Id val id: String?, val title: String, val message: String)
```

Be careful with the case of the table name - "messages" will not work, but "MESSAGES" will.